# Probability of a deleterious mutation, given an observed distribution of mutations

Tags: sampling, biostatistics, bioinformatics, hypergeometric-distribution

This problem has been driving me crazy for days, so I finally resort to asking for help here:

Consider a set of genes, where each gene consists of a sequence of letters, for example

```
GeneA: AACAGTGACACAGTGCA
GeneB: CACAGCACCAGCATTTACACAGACA
...
```

As you can see, genes have different length and compositions. Now, let's assume we observed a set of mutations in a patient:

```
GeneA: AACAGTGATACAGTGCA
               *
GeneB: CACGGCACCAGCATTAACACAGACA
          *           *
...
```

In this case, I record a `C>T`, an `A>G` and a `T>A`. Some mutations will be "deleterious", ie have an effect, while others are "silent", depending on the position in the sequence of the gene where they occur.

What I am trying to calculate is **the probability that gene A will be "hit" by at least one deleterious mutation**, given empirically observed frequencies $F_i$ of mutations of type $i \in (A \to C, A \to G, A \to T, C \to A, C \to T, C \to G, ...)$.

I have a fairly straightforward solution for the simpler case of calculating that a gene will be mutated *at all*, irrespective of whether the mutation is deleterious or not. In that case, it becomes a simple sampling without replacement problem. I simply calculate the inverse probabilities that the gene would **not** be mutated when sampling the observed number of mutations from A (and C and G and T) out of all A's in all genes. In very crude writing:

$ P(X > 0) = 1 - P(X=0, A) \cdot P(X=0, C) \cdot P(X=0, G) \cdot P(X=0, T)$

The $P(X=0, A)$ reduce to a simple hypergeometric distribution, since I know how many A's I'm sampling, how many A's there are in all genes and how many A's there are in gene X.

The problem is that when I introduce the "direction" of the mutation, the sampling analogy breaks down. I can only sample one position in the gene once, but there are three different mutations that could occur at that position, so this doesn't work:

$ P(X > 0) \ne 1 - P(X=0, A \to C) \cdot P(X=0, A \to T) \cdot P(X=0, A \to G) \cdot ...$

because the $P(X=0, A \to C/G/T)$ are not independent. I do have a list of all possible outcomes of mutating any position in any gene to any of the possible bases, but I don't know how to get around the problem that the events are not independent.

I would be very grateful for any ideas of how to approach that problem. It is tempting to just run MCMC simulations but I think the sampling space is so huge that it won't be feasible, so I'm stuck with trying to find a "closed" solution to this problem!

Answer (score 1):

I think an easier way to do this is to consider two alignments, setup an alignment score and use the Karlin-Altschul statistics given

http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/2315319

What you are trying to do (I think) is very similar to what BLAST does and it is by no means a trivial problem :)

Comment: Interesting, it didn't occur to me that this might relate to alignments. What a blast from the past! Ok, bad jokes aside, I'll have a renewed read of that classic paper...